# What is the best way to clear the harder trials in SSFIV on PS3 without a fightstick?

Tags: ps3, super-street-fighter-iv

My main is Ryu and even tho I've beaten the game on the hardest setting and gotten my rank just about to B online I still am having trouble beating about half of the trials. I was just wondering if they are possible without a fightstick (if so any tips?) or am I just basically at the wall when it comes to using a PS3 controller? Thanks guys.

Edit: Still looking for some advice. Maybe an easier answer to be found would be has anyone actually completed anyone's trials without using a fightstick? If so do you have any general tips or links to guides? Again, thanks for you time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of hardcore fighting gamers will tell you that you have to have a stick to be any good. You can ignore those people. As part of any company's standard testing routine, you must be able to do anything in the game using any of the supported input methods (controller, fight stick, fight pad, etc.). Not only that, but there are tournament players who win using pads. The trials are definitely possible.

What I would recommend if you're having trouble, is looking up a full trial run on youtube for your character. Sometimes just seeing how the combo is supposed to look is what you need to complete it. On top of that, a good way to master an extended combo is to break it into small parts (like single links or cancels) and then slowly put the pieces together.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful words, I do have to just keep at it.. just gets frustrating at times.

Comment: I know it, but you just gotta keep at it. Set little goals for yourself everyday and you'll get it soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

As motivation (I hope), follow a video showing Vesper doing some trials on a normal pad.

This is the video description.

> This video is a tribute to all pad
>   players. I started out as a pad player
>   myself in 1993 on the Snes playing
>   Street Fighter II Turbo. No matter how
>   much people bash pad players all
>   combos and tournaments are achievable
>   through practice and dedication, not
>   accessory.

[Super Street Fighter 4 Trials - Controller Pad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bm09GO6ajI)